# Java: Split main game class into separate classes

Tags: java, class

I have made a game in java however it is basically one long class. How would you go about splitting it up, for example putting all the KeyListener methods into a separate keylistener class, and putting the 50 or getImage(...) lines into a separate class.

Edit: I dont think i was clear enough with the original question, i already have a class for the player object and an animation class, however everything else, e.g. keylisteners, paint, images, mouselisteners are all in the main class. And i have no idea how to then take the code in the main class and put it in a separate class.

Comment: MVC-pattern is a good start

Answer (score 4):

By looking at the several responsibilities there are. Lets say you wrote a game of space invaders in 1 class. You could split your program into multiple classes by looking at what responsibility each object has (is 1 class really responsible for holding your spaceships position and the enemy position? What about making a spaceship and enemy class?).

Don't feel limited to splitting the "game objects" as splitting the [interface, model and domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) will increase maintainability aswell.

As you are asking about how to split up a class you might be interested in creating a Design(UML) which would improve your overview of the project (as that is likely why you are interested in splitting up your classes).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have a god class. Try my technique :

http://blue-walrus.com/2010/12/refactoring-a-god-class/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thats sort of what im after except my game is nowhere near as big, maybe only 1200 lines long. The problem im having is with the actual syntax and how to link one class to another.

Answer (score 1):

You should outsource all action in seperate classes as well as make use of superclass. Check which code you use often and merge them, make them more general. So you can save many codelines.